# Eslint module.exports parsing error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, parsing, eslint, unexpected-token

This is the error message that I am getting on Visual Studio Code.

> [ts] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.
>
> [ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
>
> [eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token . 
>   module export= (property) export=: {
>       [x: string]: any;
>       Snippet: typeof Snippet; }

This is for a class called Snippet [Some of you might find this a little bit long but I was advised to show what is inside Snippet - fyi]:

```
class Snippet {
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {any} fileName - file name.
   * @param {any} code - code.
   * @param {any} numTags - number of tags.
   * @param {any} tags - all tags.
   */
  constructor(fileName, code, ...tags) {
    this.name = fileName;
    this.code = code;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.lines = code.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
  }
  /**
   * @function
   * @name myFunction
   * @param {any} tag - check tag.
   * @return {boolean} boolean
   */
  hasTag(tagCheck) {
    if (this.tags.hasOwnProperty(tagCheck)) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.tags, tagCheck)) {
        return true;
      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried these 4:

```
module.exports = {
  Snippet:Snippet
};

module.exports = {
  Snippet
};

module.exports = {
  Snippet:Snippet,
};

module.exports = {
  Snippet,
};
```

I am still getting the same error message that I have quoted.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem? 
Thank you in advance, really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to show what's inside the Snippet class.

Comment: From the error messages it seems like you've added the `module.exports` statement inside the class' body.

Comment: @Titus Thank you. But I did not add the `module.export` inside the class body.

Comment: The indentation of the statements inside of the `hasTag` function are off. You're probably missing the class' closing curly bracket.

Comment: @Titus Thank you. After fixing the indentation, it gave me several other error messages that I fixed and now i am good to go :)